# trigonometric functions in different quadrants of cartesian coordinate system

Tags: trigonometry

Primarily we are taught that trigonometric functions were basically defined for right angled triangle but afterwards these functions were defined based on coordinate system and power series and so on. I always had a confusion regarding the transition of definition of these functions from right angled triangle to coordinate system. in case of right angled triangles we consider sine function to be the ratio of opposite side of the angle to the adjacent side but in coordinate system it is the ration of ordinate and abcissa.

So did the definitions changed or are these abcissa and ordinate issues can be easily defined in terms of these sides of a right angled triangle?

Comment: This might be clarifying: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyXgUWoAka0

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a misconception in the question. This is revealed in a comment under one of the other answers:

> ... So what basically pushed mathematicians to extend that viewpoint from acute angle to obtuse angle?

Do not assume that the sequence in which you are taught things in school is the same as the sequence in which mathematicians decided to do these things.

In fact the western/European history of trigonometry starts, as far as we know it,
with the chords of circular arcs.
Before electronic computers, people used published tables to do trigonometry;
a famous ancient trigonometric table was
[Ptolemy's table of chords](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/ma105/trighist.html). It gave chords for angles ranging from zero to $180$ degrees in steps of $1/2$ degree. No restriction to a right triangle or acute angles.

Hundreds of years ago, people used trigonometry to figure courses and distances of travel on the Earth, which they assumed at the time was a sphere. (It is just a little different from a sphere, and given the accuracy of measurements in the early days of navigation by latitude and longitude the Earth *was* a sphere for practical purposes.) But there are no right triangles on the surface of a sphere. There are so-called "spherical right triangles," but they have sides that curve along the surface of the sphere and the sine of an angle is *not* the ratio of the opposite leg to the hypotenuse of such a triangle.

Even in plane geometry we have things like the Law of Cosines for an arbitrary triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and angle $\theta$ opposite side $c$:

$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(\theta). $$

This works perfectly well for an obtuse angle $\theta,$ provided you use the standard definition of the cosine.

Also consider things like the addition formula for the sine function:

$$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha) + \cos(\beta) + \sin(\beta) + \cos(\alpha).$$

This is a useful formula. But if the sine were only a function of angles from zero to $90^\circ,$ you would have to add a condition that this formula is true only when $\alpha + \beta \leq 90^\circ.$ That would make the statement of the formula more complicated, and using it would tend to become a *lot* more complicated.

There are applications in various branches of science and engineering where we are concerned with waves that obey a rule like the sine function. If you want to know what the wave is doing after some length of time $t,$ it may have gone up and down several times during that period. This is easily described by the sine function if you allow it to accept more than $360^\circ$ as its input.

So rather than ask why mathematicians decided that trig functions should relate to any size of angle, not just the angles of a right triangle, a better question might be why someone decided that they should teach beginning students of trigonometry only about right triangles at first and wait until much later to show them trig functions of larger angles.

I think it is because the definitions in terms of right triangles are easy to explain and to use (within the limits of that course of instruction), and because it is assumed that you will be able to adapt to more complete definitions when you need to.
Moreover, in the days when people (including students) had to use printed tables to do trigonometry, people had long ago realized that it was sufficient to print the tables up to $90$ degrees and rely on the user of the table to know how to read the functions of larger angles from these same tables.
At the elementary level one might simply present the table as if the input numbers represented the whole range of the functions' input. Perhaps present-day teaching inherited this mindset although the reason for it no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've already defined $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ for angles $\theta$ between $0^\circ$ and $90^{\circ}$ via right triangles.

Now you have the following definition for general $\theta$: Let the point on the unit circle with angular coordinate $\theta$ be $M = (x,y)$. Then we define $\cos \theta = x, \sin \theta = y$.

In order for this definition to be correct, you must check that it agrees with the previous definition given for right triangles when $0^{\circ} < \theta < 90^{\circ}$. You can do this as follows. Let $O = (0,0), H = (x,0)$. Then $OHM$ is a right triangle, $\angle H = 90^{\circ}$ and $\angle O = \theta$. According to the original definition of $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$, we have
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{\text{adj}}{\text{hyp}} = \frac{OH}{OM} = \frac{x}{1} = x$$
and
$$ \sin \theta = \frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}} = \frac{HM}{OM} = \frac{y}{1} = y.$$

So the new definition agrees with the old one. The difference is that it is valid for more angles $\theta$, not just acute angles. If $\theta$ is not acute, you cannot draw a right triangle with one of the other two angles equal to $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

The transition is explained as follows:

1. Define the complex exponential map $\exp: z \mapsto e^z$.
2. Notice that $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ using Cauchy product of power series.
3. This implies for $x \in \mathbb R$, $\vert \exp(ix) \vert^2=\exp(ix )\exp(-ix)=1$.
4. $\sin x, \cos x$ are the imaginary and real part of $\exp(ix)$.
5. Those are exactly the ratio defined geometrically for a circle of radius equal to one as $\exp(ix) = \cos x +i \sin x$ according to point 3.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The definitions haven't changed,  they have been EXTENDED. You know, for example that $\sin(2\theta)= 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$ and
$\cos(2 \theta) = \cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)$.
So you can say
$$\cos(120^\circ) = \cos^2(60^\circ)  - \sin^2(60^\circ) = -\frac 12$$

$$\sin(120^\circ) = 2 \cos(60^\circ) \sin(60^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

With the circular definitions, you now know geometrically what that means and, yes, you still get right triangles.

Study them and go over all of the examples until you have your own mental images of how they work. It will be worth your time.

Comment: In case of obtuse angles, a right angled triangle is impossible to be formed. So what basically pushed mathematicians to extend that viewpoint from acute angle to obtuse angle?